# Image not responsive on home page.

Tags: url, image, rwd, cms-pages, url-key

I've added an image to my home page and when I preview the home page from CMS pages in the admin the image is responsive.

When I click on my logo the page is then fully responsive all except the image?

The URL ends index.php/home when I preview from the CMS pages panel and when I click the logo the home URL key is gone?

Comment: Can you share the code / screenshot with your question. that will help us to answer

Comment: the url is - www.asl-bathroom-store.co.uk

Comment: you can add `width: 100%;` for small screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this **css** property on your image :

```
.imageClass {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Adding the CSS works, but why  is the image responsive when a URL of www.asl-bathroom-store.co.uk/home is used? when I just use www.asl-bathroom-store.co.uk the image isn't responsive.

Comment: Maybe you theme override the image class property